# Sendmail log email content

Tags: sendmail

Is there a way I can view / log the email content sent by sendmail?

By default it only shows some header information. I wanted to inspect the actual email content.

My machine is running Fedora 13.

Answer (score 2):

I see two options to achieve this:

1. Write your own milter that logs
   content wherever you want to
2. Use MIMEDefang to do this

Answer (score 1):

There are mail-archival gateway appliances which also perform this function. A quick search on "mail archive hipaa compliance" will get you started. These appliances are often transparent, though some require setting "smarthost" in your server configuration.